# How to add to a database that has a foreign key

Tags: java

I want to make a method that adds to a database but when I try to add `salesmenId` (the foreign key) I get an error that says `int cannot be converted to Salesmen` (The Table the foreign key is from). How would I add the `salesmenId` code below

```
temp.setSalepersonId(Integer.parseInt(SalePersonIDSalesTabTxt.getText()));
```

(`temp` is the `Object` of Sales)
setSalepersonId is the method from a entity class from a database
SalePersonIDSalesTabTxt.getText() is returning a String

Comment: What is the type of an argument of `setSalepersonId`?

Comment: What SalePersonIDSalesTabTxt.getText() is returning ....

Comment: What you posted has nothing to do with databases, SQL, etc. You're calling a method expecting a Salesmen object as argument by passing it an int. That can't possibly compile. Don't want to be rude, but if you can't figure out such a basic problem yet, you shouldn't deal with databases. Learn the basics first.

Comment: Its returning a String. setSalepersonId is just an entity class that I got for importing the database onto a table so its the set method from that.

Comment: Man I really am sorry I am still in school and I am trying to learn java I know that I am lacking is most areas but I am trying to improve

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send it and Object not and Integer. JB Nizet 25 pointed this out for me.